# How to run PHASE V2.0 using ubuntu

Tags: 12.10

I wish to use PHASE v2.0. I had follow the instruction during installation. However, nothing turn out when i type in command. I always get no such directory or file.

Anyone can help on this matter? thank you.

Answer (score 0):

Did you download the binary version or the source? This software appears to be 9+ years old and was compiled against libraries of that time, so it's pretty unlikely that the binary would run on current Ubuntu. I was only able to get it to work by compiling from [source](http://www.stat.washington.edu/stephens/phase/phasecode/phase.2.0.2.source.tar.gz), and even then I had to make a few changes to account for minor code rot:

In the `Makefile`, change this:

```
CXX     = g++
```

to this:

```
CXX     = g++ -Wno-deprecated -fpermissive
```

In `pacb.lookup.cpp`, change this:

```
#include<iostream.h>
```

to this:

```
#include <iostream>
```

Please note that the site says:

> If you have not already done so, you must agree to the [license](http://www.assertion.net/software) before proceeding.

... yet the license link is broken, so it may not be possible currently to download or use this software without infringing the author's copyright. If you intend to make serious use of it, I would recommend contacting Matthew Stephens to ask for a copy of the license.